# Tooltip for fullcalendar in year view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to add tooltip for the fullcalendar in year view. I tried with the below one but it added tooltip to month view. I tried with google but did not find anything related to this. Is there any other way to add a tooltip in year view?

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent,jsEvent) {
            xOffset = 10;
            yOffset = 30;
            $("body").append(calEvent.tooltip);
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(jsEvent.clientY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(jsEvent.clientX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
    },
    eventMouseout: function(calEvent,jsEvent) {
        $("#tooltip").remove(); 
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting a year view? The available views are defined in the documentation. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.title + '</div>';
    var $tooltip = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');

    $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        $tooltip.fadeIn('500');
        $tooltip.fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        $tooltip.css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        $tooltip.css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
},

eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    $(this).css('z-index', 8);
    $('.tooltipevent').remove();
},
```

Comment: please change "var $tootlip" to "var $tooltip". And thanks for the example. Work like a charm

Comment: Context please? Is this in `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({});` or part of `'renderEvent'`

Answer (score 31):

You can use the html title attribute without any tooltip lib :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2014-01-01',
            tooltip: 'This is a cool event'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.attr('title', event.tooltip);
    }
});
```

Comment: Since jQuery 1.6 prop() should be used: `element.prop("title", event.title);`

Comment: Great help! Worked fine. For those who uses a newer version of fullcalendar, there is a tooltip function that may help too: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display  It allows more details in the tooltip.

Answer (score 9):

As fullcalendar has changed the events in the latest version as per [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-clicking-hovering) I am changing the [jincheng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10749066/6082645) with little more detailed answer

The popup will look like this

[image]

**It doesn't need any js or css plugins**

you can change the event data or payload with one more object for tooltip stuff and use it in your js like

```
        events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2019-01-01',
            popup: {
                title: 'This is the title',
                descri: 'This is the description',
            }
        }
        // more events here
        ],
        eventMouseEnter: function(info) {
            var tis=info.el;
            var popup=info.event.extendedProps.popup;
            var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="top:'+($(tis).offset().top-5)+'px;left:'+($(tis).offset().left+($(tis).width())/2)+'px"><div>' + popup.title + '</div><div>' + popup.descri + '</div></div>';
            var $tooltip = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');

//            If you want to move the tooltip on mouse movement then you can uncomment it
//            $(tis).mouseover(function(e) {
//                $(tis).css('z-index', 10000);
//                $tooltip.fadeIn('500');
//                $tooltip.fadeTo('10', 1.9);
//            }).mousemove(function(e) {
//                $tooltip.css('top', e.pageY + 10);
//                $tooltip.css('left', e.pageX + 20);
//            });
        },
        eventMouseLeave: function(info) {
            console.log('eventMouseLeave');
            $(info.el).css('z-index', 8);
            $('.tooltipevent').remove();
        },
```

The css for the tooltip to look like the above screenshot

```
.tooltipevent{
    width:200px;/*
    height:100px;*/
    background:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10001;
    transform:translate3d(-50%,-100%,0);
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px #888888;
    line-height: 1rem;
}
.tooltipevent div{
    padding:10px;
}
.tooltipevent div:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:White;
    background-color:#888888;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.tooltipevent div:last-child{
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltipevent div:last-child::after, .tooltipevent div:last-child::before{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:solid 5px transparent;/*
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px #888888;*/
    border-bottom:0;
    border-top-color:whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    bottom:-4px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.tooltipevent div:last-child::before{
    border-top-color:#888888;
    bottom:-5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @jafarbtech, your code is working really as it is, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

since 1.5 version, you can use qtip (i also use tipsy but it should work with tooltip) to display a tip on an event:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            description: 'This is a cool event'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description
        });
    }
});
```

doc source: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

hope this helps

Comment: this also added the tooltip in month view, nothing happened in year view. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here another implementation

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) { var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:130px;height:100px;background:#aed0ea;position:absolute;z-index:10001;"> Title: ' + calEvent.title + '</div>'; var $tool = $(tooltip).appendTo('body');
$(this).mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
            $tool.fadeIn('500');
            $tool.fadeTo('10', 1.9);
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    $tool.css('top', e.pageY + 10);
    $tool.css('left', e.pageX + 20);
});
},
eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
$(this).css('z-index', 8);
$('.tooltipevent').remove();
},
```

---