# How to Hide Event time in "month" view of of p:schedule in primefaces?

Tags: events, primefaces, schedule

Is it possible to hide time for event in "**Month**" view ? I am using `<p:schedule>` and i only want to show the Event Title in the calendar's month view.

Hope there is a way.... help please

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the time by setting the `fc-event-time` css class to `display:none;`

Like this

```
.fc-event-time{
    display:none;
}
```

But you better give it a more specific id , like this (you can set `prependId="false"` in your form that surrounds the scheduler)

```
#myscheduleId .fc-event-time{
    display:none;
}
```

just make sure to include the css in the end (in your `h:body` for example)

Comment: Thanks @Deniel
i have changed the css and got it... one more help plzzz
How to show some text on mouse-hover on date cell in the month view ?

Comment: There is no straight forward way to do so in primefaces , but you can do it if you will use the jQUery plugin FullCalendar that is being used by primefaces http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ (ofcourse it wont be that easy ) , take a look in here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802179/tooltip-for-fullcalendar-in-year-view

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute rightHeaderTemplate. default its value is month,agendaWeek,agendaDay. change to rightHeaderTemplate ="agendaWeek,agendaDay"