# Getting Angular UI Calendar to work with UI-Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am trying to display a tooltip on angular UI calendarEvent's mouse-hover. I managed to do this as explained in the following thread,
[Tooltip for fullcalendar in year view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802179/tooltip-for-fullcalendar-in-year-view)

```
    $scope.eventMouseover = function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent">' + calEvent.description + '</div>';
        $("body").append(tooltip);
        $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
            $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
            $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
            $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
        }).mousemove(function (e) {
            $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
            $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
        });
    }

    $scope.eventMouseout = function (calEvent, jsEvent) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 8);
        $('.tooltipevent').remove();
    },
```

Obviously, this is not the best way to do this. With the latest UI-Bootstrap, we have a much nicer looking tooltips. Did anyone successfully integrated these tooltips with the Angular-UI Calendar?

**Update 1** : As explained in http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ , I tried overriding the eventRender and simply added the tool tip attribute to the calendarEvent divs. Still not working. I can see that even the mouseover and mouseout events are not added to the those calendarEvent divs that contain 'tooltip' attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you add this function to the calendar config it will work.

```
$scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) { 
  $timeout(function(){
    $(element).attr('tooltip', event.title);
    $compile(element)($scope);
  });
};
```

Anything can be placed in the tooltip attribute. even {{bindings}}

The $timeout is there because $scope.$apply must be called. By using $timeout with no delay it is ensured that a digest will be called without ever throwing a "digest in progress" error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you explain the job of $compile() here?

Comment: Sure. $compile is taking the template DOM (the element with the newly added tooltip attribute) and running the function collectDirectives on it. This function is looking for unique values, such as tooltip. Once the unique values are collected they return a composite link function which is called with the $scope as its parameter. This ultimately combines the newly compiled element to the AngularJS scope tree and interpolates all values with that specific scope object.

Comment: I just updated the demo site to use this technique. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/