# $sce.trustAsHtml returned value not compiled by $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive, angularjs-compile

I'm trying to make a custom popover with html by using [angular bootstrap-ui popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) with fullcalendar's events as described here: [Getting Angular UI Calendar to work with UI-Bootstrap Tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128636/947111)

But I need to use more complicated popover and need to use `uib-popover-html` as following:

```
 $scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) { 

        var test = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b> Hello World! </b>');
        element.attr({'uib-popover-html':  test,
                     'popover-trigger' : 'mouseenter',
                     'popover-append-to-body': true});

        $compile(element)($scope);
    };
```

But when it throws the following error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary
>   expression at column 1 of the expression [ **Hello World!** ]
>   starting at [ **Hello World!** ].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4923), my assumption is that `uib-popover-html` is not even intended to work.

BUT there is workaround: just use `uib-popover-template` instead:

```
$scope.eventRender = function(event, element, view) {
  element.attr({
    'uib-popover-template': "'myTooltipTemplate'",
    'popover-trigger': 'mouseenter',
    'popover-append-to-body': true
  });
  $compile(element)($scope);
};
```

Here is a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/4wf31bkw/

Comment: Thank you, you solution works but I forget to mention that I need to generate popover template dynamically, is it possible? I've played a while with your code and statically it works, but dynamically it throws exception. I forgot to mention this in my original question, so I will accept your answer, and perhaps open new question.

Comment: @Anatoly did you find any solution for generating it dynamicaly?

Comment: @FabioG, no, but I haven't look actively yet. From what I have seen across the internet I have two options. Or custom directive, or use angular-strap library.